# Error: while importing 'app', an ImportError was raised: ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'flask'

Tags: python, flask, importerror, markup

I am quite a beginner in Python but I'm desperately looking for a solution for the problem that

> Markup cannot be imported from "flask"

Context: for a project at university, I am trying to build a flask application. I am set by now and got no errors until the end when I wanted to run flask and this error appears.

The traceback looks like this:

```
File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 247, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\app\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from app import routes, models

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\app\routes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app, tables, models

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\app\tables.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_table import Table, Col

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_table\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .table import Table, create_table

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_table\table.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .columns import Col

  File "C:\Users\phili\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_table\columns.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Markup, url_for
```

These are the installed packages:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KpGB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja8qB.png)

I almost read every thread asked Ai but no solution was suitable from my point of view.

Due to I am as I said a beginner the solution might be pretty simple but i cannot find it.

Thanks in advance and I hope the provided information is enough.

I tried to reinstall the packages, tried to change the code which was related to the Markup-order, read threads but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue with flask-table.  https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/issues/137